# Update each code with max value

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a table that looks something like

```
CODE    NUMBER     MAX_NUMBER
1001    1          
1001    2  
1001    3  
1001    4 
1006    1 
1006    2 
1006    3
1008    1
1008    2
```

I am looking for an update statement to set the max number for each code in the MAX_NUMBER field for every row. So for example the table should look like the following when update is complete

```
CODE    NUMBER     MAX_NUMBER
1001    1          4
1001    2          4
1001    3          4
1001    4          4
1006    1          3
1006    2          3 
1006    3          3
1008    1          2
1008    2          2
```

I know the following select

```
SELECT CODE, MAX(NUMBER) AS 'MAX'
FROM table
GROUP BY CODE
```

will give me

```
CODE      MAX
1001      4
1006      3
1008      2
```

Just need the update to put the max number in for every row

Thanks

Comment: Which SQL, MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle?

Comment: Or a better question: why in the world would you want to duplicate data like that in your database?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Storing computed values is risky. Data inconsistency is not uncommon. (If absolutely required, set up strict column privileges and use triggers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (MS-SQL Server)

```
UPDATE <table> SET max_number=xx.MAX
FROM 
(
    SELECT CODE, MAX(NUMBER) AS 'MAX'
    FROM <table>
    GROUP BY CODE
) xx
WHERE xx.code=<table>.code
```

A different approach would be to create a view and reference that instead of the actual table.

```
create view TableWithMax
as
select mm.code,mm.number,xx.max as max_number
from mm.table 
join ( 
    SELECT CODE, MAX(NUMBER) AS 'MAX'
    FROM table
    GROUP BY CODE) xx
on xx.code = mm.code
```

You will pay a bit of a performance hit, but your data will be accurate

Comment: No problem, but the comments about what you are trying to achieve are valid.   The code above will be a snapshot, the minute another row is added, the max number value become wrong.   You know your application, just be aware of the potential data problem.

Comment: This table represents a staging table I will be using for mapping The data will not be duplicated in live system tables. Thanks again